Schedule View: INDEX MATCH from table and return multiple cells into one
Please find the reference Google Sheet here.
(View only access, please File > Make A Copy)
I am trying to take a data table for a work conference schedule of sessions ("Session Details" sheet) and have it automatically populate a vertical agenda format ("Master Agenda" sheet).
On the "End Goal" sheet, you can see what I am ultimately trying to accomplish.
I have currently set up the following formula in C16 to pull data from the "Session Details" sheet to populate the Session Name into the "Master Agenda" sheet:
=IFNA(INDEX('Session Details'!$E:$E,MATCH(1,('Session Details'!$A:$A=$C$2)*('Session Details'!$B:$B=$A16)*('Session Details'!$D:$D=C$3),0)))

Which is working well, as it finds the 10:00 AM Marketing Session occurring on Monday, September 9 and returns the Session Name:

What I can't figure out how to do (if possible), is to then pull in the remaining relevant data for that session (i.e. Start Time, End Time, Presenters, Location) to also populate the cell.
Ideally, I would want it to look like it does on the "End Goal" sheet (see below) and span the entire length of the session (from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM):

Any way to utilize the INDEX MATCH formula I have currently to pull in other relevant data from the same row and ideally display it in a readable format (merged cell or not)?

you won't be able to achieve that with a worksheet formula. Your second screenshot shows a merged cell that spans several rows and has bold and italic formatting. Neither of these can be done with a formula. you would need to engage programming.

@teylyn – Thanks for reply. Would it be possible you think if the cell wasn't merged and it just returned the other values (time, presenters, etc) in the following cells?

Is it feasible to put session details in a table? It would make it much easier to reference columns, among other benefits.

Would you be willing for an approach that uses apps script instead of solely using a formula?


Here's one formulaic approach which you may adapt accordingly (does not give your idealistic expected output of merged style thing though; hopefully someone will contribute via a script):
=map(A4:A69,lambda(Ξ,map(C3:E3,lambda(Γ,let(Λ,'Session Details'!A2:index('Session Details'!H:H,match(,0/('Session Details'!A:A<>""))),Σ,lambda(x,choosecols(Λ,x)),
 ifna(filter(Σ(5)&char(10)&to_text(Σ(2))&" - "&to_text(Σ(3))&char(10)&Σ(6)&char(10)&Σ(8), Σ(2)=Ξ, Σ(4)=Γ, Σ(1)=C2)))))))



This is working perfectly, thank you! Yes I wish I could have merged cells, but after inputting the formula into C4 and the results populate, I can select the necessary cells I want and merge them to span the duration of the session and it all still works... so just a bit of manual merging there, but saving a bunch of time aggregating all the data from the "Session Details" sheet
I am accepting this answer – however, if anyone reading this has any ideas/solves to automatically merge the cells (or make them appear as such) to span the full time duration of a session, please let me know

Here's a quick draft to get the details - works only in Excel (Microsoft 365). I will try to get Google Sheets version later. Getting merged cells via formula is not possible to my knowledge (as teylyn also commented).
Using variables is my preferred way, hopefully you don't mind it. Compact code is not my goal here :)
This is an (dynamic) array formula, entered in a single cell, C4 in the example:
=LET(
    session_details, 'Session Details'!$A$2:$H$8,

    format_detail, LAMBDA(detail_row,
        LET(
            start_time, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 2),
            end_time, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 3),
            session_name, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 5),
            presenter, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 6),
            location, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 8),
            newline, CHAR(10),
            time_format, "hh:mm AM/PM",
            CONCAT(
                session_name,
                newline,
                TEXT(start_time, time_format),
                " - ",
                TEXT(end_time, time_format),
                newline,
                presenter,
                newline,
                location
            )
        )
    ),

    b_units, C3:E3,
    start_times, A4:A69,
    session_date, C2,
    date, INDEX(session_details, , 1),
    start_time, INDEX(session_details, , 2),
    b_unit, INDEX(session_details, , 4),
    arr, LAMBDA(n, CHOOSE(n, start_times, b_units)),
    details, MAP(
        arr({1}),
        arr({2}),
        LAMBDA(session_start, session_bu,
            LET(
                detail_row, MATCH(
                    1,
                    (date = session_date) * (start_time = session_start) * (b_unit = session_bu),
                    0
                ),
                IF(ISNA(detail_row), "", format_detail(detail_row))
            )
        )
    ),

    details
)

(I'm using arr lambda by DjC to map with two arrays in this manner - instead of MAKEARRAY.)
Result


Google Sheets version
using MAKEARRAY and ARRAYFORMULA:
=LET(
    session_details, 'Session Details'!$A$2:$H$8,
    session_date, C2,
    date, INDEX(session_details, , 1),
    start_time, INDEX(session_details, , 2),
    b_unit, INDEX(session_details, , 4),
    format_detail, LAMBDA(detail_row,
        LET(
            start_time, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 2),
            end_time, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 3),
            session_name, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 5),
            presenter, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 6),
            location, INDEX(session_details, detail_row, 8),
            newline, CHAR(10),
            time_format, "hh:mm AM/PM",
            CONCATENATE(
                session_name,
                newline,
                TEXT(start_time, time_format),
                " - ",
                TEXT(end_time, time_format),
                newline,
                presenter,
                newline,
                location
            )
        )
    ),
    b_units, C3:E3,
    start_times, A4:A69,
    arr, LAMBDA(n, CHOOSE(n, start_times, b_units)),
    details, arrayformula(MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(start_times),
        COLUMNS(b_units),
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            LET(
                session_start, INDEX(start_times, r, 1),
                session_bu, INDEX(b_units, 1, c),
                detail_row, MATCH(1, (date = session_date) * (start_time = session_start) * (b_unit = session_bu), 0),
                IF(ISNA(detail_row), "", format_detail(detail_row))
            )
        )
    )),
    details
)

Result:


– first off I appreciate the time you spent on this! I'm using the Google Sheets formula and it's working when I put it in C4  Only issue I am running into is that when I then add a new session on the "Sessions Details" sheet, it isn't reflecting/updating on the "Master Agenda" sheet. Otherwise this solution is working exactly as I intended and I upvoted it
That all being said, another solution I received from someone else on this thread is also working and is doing a good job of populating as I add new sessions.

Thanks for testing. Please increase the range in session_details, 'Session Details'!$A$2:$H$8, to a2:h100 for example - and let me know.

Yep – that fixed the problem, I get it now. I ended up just updating that line in the formula to be, "session_details, 'Session Details'!A2:H," ... so that now reflects updates from Session Details page
